# Font Awesone 5 url is wrong

Tags: webpack, fonts, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I use Webpack 4 and Font Awesone 5 (FA).

When I import FA as this:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

Icons **showing** on this levels:

```
http://some.com
https://some.com/first/
```

And **not showing** on next site levels:

```
1. https://some.com/first/next/
2. https://some.com/first/next/level
```

When I open network tabs in Chrome devtools and look the second url, I see, what the browser try to load fonts throgh use this path:

```
https://some.com/first/next/web/fonts/fa-solid...*.woff
```

[image]

As we see, browser use relative path to get fonts,Then how should use the absolute path.  I think, maybe the problem is caused by the fact that I did wrong fonts import via Webpack. 
I did import fonts in this way:

```
$fa-font-path: '/web/fonts'; 
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
```

I assumed that this option will work correctly, but in this case nothing works at all. What I doing is wrong?

ps. All font files present in the fonts home directory and have access trought 
browser via `https://some.com/web/fonts/`